# Insert text in a div container

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea where i get it's content and send it to database via ajax. 
When i get such content and insert it in a DIV, new lines are not considered, so the content is pasted as a whole without LF.

I used jQuery templates for printing the result of my query and within the template the mentioned div is:

```
<div class="message">${msg}</div>
```

where ${msg} is the message gathered from the database with CR.

Is there anything I could do for avoiding that?

Comment: Do a find and replace? Replace CR with CRLF.

Comment: The question is that I want to show the new lines when the message is placed into the div.

Comment: Did you inspect the resulting div with Firebug? If the <br /> are here there should by newlines...

Comment: <br /> is printed when the message is inserted into the div.

Answer (score 2):

You use php, do you?
So you can convert normal line breaks (`\n`) to HTML line breaks (`<br />`) with [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: I have just used such function and in the database are replaced with <br /> but when i put the content within the div, happens the same.